# Which profile can I use to monitor the temperature in BLE?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, temperature

I want to monitor the temperature of a room in BLE, but it seems that BLE only support HTS profile for health. May I use this profile, or I need to create a new profile on my own?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use it, but it wouldn't respect the specifications, and a user/developer may be confused by it.

Answer (score 1):

How about Environmental Sensing [Profile](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=294796)/[Service](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=294797) and their [Assigned numbers](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/Environmental-Sensing-Service-Characteristics) ?